# Regex for remove domain in hostname

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to capture only the hostname within this date, but my regex is broken when inside the hostname, there are `.` because I remove the **hostname domain**

**REGEX**

```
^([^;@#.\s]+)
```

**DATA**

```
srvdata;172.24.154.210
srvnet;10.16.0.1
srvdata2 300
#srvdata3
srvdata3 #srvdata3
srvdata4.domain.com
srvdata.4.domain.com
```

**OUTPUT**

```
srvdata
srvnet
srvdata2
srvdata3
srvdata4
srvdata
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
srvdata
srvnet
srvdata2
srvdata3
srvdata4
srvdata.4
```

[**REGEX101**](https://regex101.com/r/KQNbSr/3/)

Comment: `^[^#]+?(?:\.\d+)?(?=[. ;])` Would do it per the data you've presented. https://regex101.com/r/oOUBjD/1

Comment: that won't work if you don't define some more rules. Your rules are flawed. Regex need pattern and exact rules. You say: yeah sometimes the point is not part of the domain name but sometimes it is.
How should we know? You have to add more rules like: when it's only one letter after the point it still is the domain name or have a list of domain names and filter like that.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus my problem is servdata.4.domain.com, I needed srvdata.4

Comment: @LuisHenrique see my updated comment

Comment: @Boendal Can you help with an example?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus perfect!!!!!

Comment: You need to define the rules. What @MonkeyZeus did with his newest regex is that when after the point there are only numbers then it is still the domain name but if you have a name like: servdata.4a.domain.com it will return servdata

Comment: @MonkeyZeus comment on the answer so i can select

Comment: so he "invented" a new rule. If this is your intention then I think it works.

Comment: @Boendal true :/

Comment: as I told you, you need more rules otherwise it won't work so you need to know your data more.

Comment: @Boendal ok, thanks !!!

Comment: and as a reminder: it's a stupid idea to have "." in hostnames... exactly in situations like this.

Comment: I agree, but I didn't define the hostnames: /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work per the data you've presented:

```
^[^#]+?(?:\.\d+)?(?=[. ;])
```

https://regex101.com/r/oOUBjD/1

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
(.*)(?=\.domain\.com)
```

To test it out: [link](https://regexpad.com/?r=(.*)(%3F%3D%5C.domain%5C.com)&f=&m0=srvdata.4.domain.com#p-javascript)

I used lookahead to see to capture the hostname string right before the domain.  Obviously if you have multiple domains or no domain you need to update that above regex to include those options.

Comment: This fails to capture two-thirds of the data OP presented...